# Grabbing specific data column from dataset with pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm using a dataset that is about birds. The dataset contains their ID (Chick (ID)), weight(weight (g)), day (time (days)), and what kind of diet (Diet (ID)) they're following.

The weight increases for each day, and if a bird hasn't reached day 21 it has died. I want to be able to grab the data from the birds that haven't survived by filtering it through ID.
For example, I've managed to make a sub-dataset that only takes the birds that follow Diet ID 1 in the code snippet below and used Seaborn to show it visually.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns


df = pd.read_csv(r"-file-")
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
df
groupOne = df[df['Diet (ID)'] == 1]
sns.relplot(data=groupOne, x="Time (days)", y="weight (g)", hue="Chick (ID)", kind="line", marker = 'o', col ='Diet (ID)')
```

I want to do something similar by making a sub dataset out of that groupOne set. Where I grab 3 birds that have the Chick (ID) 8, 15, and 18 and put those three in a dataset.
Something like this, and put these 3 datasets in another sub dataset and use seaborn to show those 3 visually. But it's not working.

```
groupOneDeadOne = groupOne[(groupOne['Chick (ID)'] == 8)]
groupOneDeadTwo = groupOne[(groupOne['Chick (ID)'] == 15)]
groupOneDeadThree = groupOne[(groupOne['Chick (ID)'] == 18)]
```

Basically where I just choose the 3 birds with those 3 ids and put them in a dataset and then use that dataset to show it visually with seaborn as I did previously. Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.isin()` to match multiple values:

```
groupOneSub = groupOne[groupOne['Chick (ID)'].isin((8, 15, 18))]
```

Test code: (please provide sample data next time)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "Chick (ID)": [1,2,5,8,8,13,15,18],
    "dummy": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
})

sub = df[df['Chick (ID)'].isin((8, 15, 18))]
```

Output:

```
sub
Out[31]: 
   Chick (ID)  dummy
3           8      1
4           8      1
6          15      1
7          18      1
```

Comment: Thank you, was exactly what I wanted!